# Error using to_sql(… , method='multi') with MS Access

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-access

I am inserting data into a Microsoft Access database using the following code:

```
test_data.to_sql('employee_table', cnxn, index=False, if_exists='append', chunksize=10, method='multi')
```

This gives error:

```
AttributeError: 'CompileError' object has no attribute 'orig'
```

There is no error when just using the following i.e. no `method` option:

```
test_data.to_sql('employee_table', cnxn, index=False, if_exists='append', chunksize=10)
```

Comment: Then why not use the code that does not error? Does it commit the data? What is the issue here? Why do you need the additional parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you cited is a subsequent exception caused by the original error (earlier in the stack trace):

> sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: The 'access' dialect with current database version settings does not support in-place multirow inserts.

The `method="multi"` option of `.to_sql()` wants to create multi-row INSERT statements, often in the form of a "table-value constructor", e.g.,

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) VALUES (1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')
```

and Access SQL does not support those.

If a plain `.to_sql()` (without `method=`) is too slow for a large DataFrame then consider the alternative approach documented in the wiki:

https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access/wiki/%5Bpandas%5D-faster-alternative-to-.to_sql()-for-large-uploads